# Hide table content in angular js, Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

im new to angular, i have a table like this which is having angular data, its not having any controller or model. Its just displaying in html.

```
    <table  width="98%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" class="labels" align="center" id="locc">

      <tr style="color:#000;font-size:15px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background-color:gold;background-repeat:repeat-x; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;"
       height="30" >
        <td  width="211"  align="center">COMMODITY / CITY</td>
        <td  width="149" align="center" valign="middle"  >BUY</td>
        <td  width="175" align="center" valign="middle" >SELL</td> 
      </tr>
      <tbody ng-repeat="item in newsData" >
        <div id="comm">
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="40"   >
          <td  align="center" id="commodity" style="border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;color:#000;font-size:15px" >{{item.COMMODITY}}</td>
          <td  align="center" valign="middle" style="border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;color:#000000;font-size:20px" class="{{item.BCOL}}" ><div  >&nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.BUY}}&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></td>
          <td  align="center" valign="middle" style="border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;color:#000000;font-size:20px" class="{{item.SCOL}}"  ><div >{{item.SELL}}&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></td>

        </tr></div>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

The output of the following is like this..

[image]

By default its loading all COMMODITY values are displayed by using "repeat",

What i want is only first two COMMODITY to be displayed rest i want to remove.. Please help me to do this..
I want only these two values "GOLD999[IMPORTED][BLR]", "SILVER-30KG[ALL LOCATION]"

Comment: do you mean that you want to show first two row's ? or to display the whole table as is but hide all cell that comes after the second cell inside commodity column just?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AngularJS `limitTo` filter as documented [here](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_limitto.asp).

In you code

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in newsData | limitTo : 2" >
```

Comment: One more thing.. I want to send this data to display in mobile app.. How can  i make this into JSON and send them as a api??